# is there an error i am not spotting on the dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display this dropdown but on click nothing it does not drop down. I have installed the twitter bootrap gem... please advice. I have tried playing with the gem but nothing has happend. I even copied an example of a `nav` code snippet from bootstrap.com but nothing happend.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top " >
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Recipes",root_path, class: "bt  btn-lg btn-success" ,id:"logo"%>
    <div class="nav_item">
        <%= link_to "Edit Profile",edit_user_registration_path, class:" btn btn-default btn-warning", style: 'margin-top: 10px;' %> 
    </div>
    

     <div class="nav_item">
        <%= link_to "Link one","", class:" btn btn-default btn-warning", style: 'margin-top: 10px;' %>
    </div>
     <div class="nav_item">
        <%= link_to "Link one","", class: "btn btn-default btn-warning", style: 'margin-top: 10px;' %>
    </div>
     <div class="nav_item">
        <%= link_to "New Recipe",new_recipe_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-warning", style: 'margin-top: 10px;' %>
    </div>
    <ul class= "nav_item">
      <li class= "dropdown">    
        <%= link_to '#', class:'btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle'=>'dropdown' do%>
            <%=current_user.name%><b class='caret'></b >
        <%end %>
        <ul class= 'dropdown-menu'>
          <li ><%= link_to "View profile", user_show_path(current_user)%></li>
          <li ><%= link_to "Edit profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li class= 'divider'></li>
          <li ><%= link_to "New Recipe", new_recipe_path %></li>
          <li class= 'divider'></li>
          <li ><%= button_to "Log Out ", destroy_user_session_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a better look at the Bootstrap docs again.

If you are using v4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

I think your classes are kind of off, for example `nav_item` should be `nav-item`, you are also missing a unorganized list `navbar-nav` that surrounds your `<li> nav-item` tags (`nav-item dropdown`if you want a dropdown etc.. I see a lot of things that are not right in your code.

I would also avoid using a container div inside your navbar.